# Get Axes Range of Plot?

Tags: plotting, syntax

Say I have some plot

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x,0,10}] (*as an example*)
```

Is there a way I can get the x and y axes min/max values from the "plot" variable?

If I wanted the image sizes I could do

```
ImageDimensions[plot]
```

I'm looking for something like this but for the axes (either total length or min/max values). I want to draw some additional graphics on the plot but it needs to be appropriately scaled.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't give a complete answer from mobile, but you will want to check out the Scaled function, plus my GetGeometry function in my recent question "Context dependent functions"

Comment: are you actually looking for the coordinate range on the plot or are you thinking in terms of the image? The plots `Plot[10^6 Sin[x],{x,0,10}]` and `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]` look very similar, you could place them on top of each other, however the y-range of one is +-10^6, while the other is +-1. Both plots would be 600 points wide and `600/GoldenRatio` high. Axes dimensions in printer points would be similar.

Comment: Strongly related: "[How to get the real `PlotRange`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280)"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Also

```
PlotRange[plot]
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plot]
Last @@ AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange]
PlotRange /. plot[[2]]
```

all give

```
(* {{0.,10.},{-0.999999,1.}} *)
```

**Note:** Regarding usage of ***`PlotRange` as a function***, it is undocumented, and the earliest reference I could find on this site is this answer dated Oct 11, 2012:

- [The same range on each plot in a
  grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11887/125).

Since then, also used in

- [PlotRange adjustments with BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19890/125)
- [How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18656/125)
- [Plotting discrete data but not using DiscretePlot function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17918/125)

Comment: +1 `PlotRange[plot]` is a very interesting answer - an option rule that can behave as a function.  I didn't see anything in the documentation that PlotRange (or other options, for that matter) could behave in this fashion.

Comment: @bob, thank you for the vote. It is not documented afaik. My initial discovery was pure accident. I used  it in several answers on this site but i cannot find any of them when i search now.

Comment: Mr.Wizard could not recall [recently](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73523/19960) where he learnt that PlotRange trick. Now I know it was probably from you and that it is indeed not documented ... interesting ;)

Comment: @SquareOne, still searching earlier posts - no success so far.

Comment: This is how to you can make the additional functionality of the Options visible: 
`ClearAttributes[Evaluate[Options[Graphics]〚All, ,1〛], ReadProtected]`
`Information /@ Options[Graphics]〚All, 1〛`
unfortunately the result is that `PlotRange` is the only option of `Graphics` that is also a `Function`. Its `Definition` is: `PlotRange[- GraphicsArray-]:=With[{System`Dump`res=Graphics[-GraphicsArray-]},PlotRange[System`Dump`res]/;System`Dump`GRTest[System`Dump`res]]` and something similar with -RasterGraphics-. Really interesting, maybe there are more options like this to find!

Comment: @sacratus, good observation. It is interesting that the function argument can also be `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow` or GraphicsColumn`, in addition to `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`. Also interesting is that  the code does not really give any information about the implementation of `PlotRange[g_Graphics]`.

Comment: The readable part of its definitions suggests that it was written to work with pre-v6 graphics.  But it does not work with the new `Legended` (`Show`, etc. do).  My conclusion is that this usage should be probably be considered deprecated.  Maybe it was standard in some old version.

Answer (score 3):

`FilterRules[AbsoluteOptions[plot], PlotRange]` does the trick

```
(*{PlotRange -> {{0., 10.}, {-0.999999, 1.}}} *)
```

Not sure if this is an exhaustive answer.

Comment: Uh... yeah, obvious solution is obvious. My thinking gets boxy after 7 hours at Schiphol. The harder part is getting the absolute (or printer, or whatever you wish to call them) coordinates, at which I hinted in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, while I wait for my flight, here's some code that'll give you everything there is to know about a plot.

```
GetGeometry[g_Graphics] :=
    Module[{
        q,
        dim,
        plotrange=PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[g,PlotRange],
        },

        q=Rasterize[Show[g,
                    Epilog->{Annotation[Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0,0}],ImageScaled[{1,1}]],"One","Region"],
                            Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}],Scaled[{1,1}]],"Two","Region"]}],"Regions"][[-2;;-1,2]];

        s=q[[1,2]]-q[[1,1]];
        q=q[[2]];
        dim=If[Norm[s-ImageDimensions[g]]<Sqrt[2],s,ImageDimensions[g]];

        {
        "PlotRange"->plotrange,
        "ImageSize"->dim,
        "PlotRangeSize"->q[[2]]-q[[1]],
        "ImagePadding"->{{q[[1,1]],dim[[1]]-q[[2,1]]},{dim[[2]]-q[[2,2]],q[[1,2]]}},
        "AspectRatio"->(q[[2,2]]-q[[1,2]])/(q[[2,1]]-q[[1,1]]),
        "ImageScaledToScaled"->(({{-q[[1,1]],-dim[[2]]+q[[2,2]]},{dim[[1]]-q[[2,1]],q[[1,2]]}})/(q[[2]]-q[[1]]))+{{0,0},{1,1}}
        }
    ]
```

**Edit**

The code above had some excessive definitions which I removed (the full version of my function calculates the amount of padding necessary for the ticks and frame labels).

Most of the output of the function is self-explanatory, but `"PlotRangeSize"` gives the size of the `PlotRange` in printer points and `"ImageScaledToScaled"` gives the coordinates of `Scaled[{0,0}]` and `Scaled[{1,1}]` in terms of `ImageScaled`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cases[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], _[PlotRange, x_] :> x, -1][[1]]
(*{{0, 10}, {-0.999999, 1.}})*
```