# Dimension of plotting window vs PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics

For example, let's say I'm plotting this function, `Plot[x, {x,-3,2}]`. From the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78329/19692) the plot range is `{{-3,2},{-3,2}}`, as expected. However, the coordinate plane clearly extends beyond this range, which you can see if you set `Frame->True`. Is there a way to determine the true dimensions of the plotting window? Something along the lines of calling the dimensions of the frame in the units used by the axes?

If I were to eyeball it, it looks like there are margins of about 0.1 in the horizontal direction and between 0.28 and 0.3 in the vertical direction. This would make the dimensions approximately 5.2x5.6, so the plot takes up around 85% of the total space allotted for the plot.

Comment: Is `PlotRangePadding` what you are after?

Comment: I could certainly work with that, but that's not quite what I was looking for. I'm more interested in the dimensions of the space that `PlotRangePadding` removes.

Comment: I linked a topic I think answers your question together with documentation. Take a look at pages for relevant options, `PlotRangePadding` gives 4% more range.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling that all plots would have a uniform amount of "fluff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPlot = Plot[x, {x, -3, 2}];

AbsoluteOptions[myPlot, {PlotRange, PlotRangePadding}]
```

{PlotRange -> {{-3., 2.}, {-3., 2.}},

PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], 
    Scaled[0.05]}}}