# Getting axes range from plot (of the plot)

Tags: plotting

Related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78324/get-axes-range-of-plot) in a way. After making a plot, I'd like to get the plot range (not the range of the function, but the range chosen for plotting which usually leaves some buffer room). I've tried `Plot[Sin[x], {x,0,10}]//PlotRange` but that instead gives what seems to be the range of the function.

Comment: @Kuba, I can't get the accepted answer from that post to work.  If you look at the test at the end of my answer here, and replace `FullRange` with `completePlotRange` then I just get error messages.

Comment: @JasonB I would go with ``Charting`get2DPlotRange@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]``

Comment: That works, but I must say that having hidden functions just takes all the fun out of it.

Comment: @JasonB maybe but quite often they are more stable than documented :)

Comment: @JasonB I just have checked `completePlotRange` (from the top of my [answer in the linked thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280)) with the test examples at the end of [your answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100819/280) using *Mathematica* 10.3 and it works like a charm producing output similar but only approximately equal to your's without any error messages. Please try it again with fresh kernel.

Comment: @JasonB `completePlotRange/@{Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}],Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10},PlotRange->{-2,2}],Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10},PlotRange->All],Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10},PlotRange->{{-20.322,2200},{-2,2}}]}` returns `{{{-0.208333,10.2083},{-1.11111,1.11111}},{{-0.208333,10.2083},{-2.,2.}},{{-0.208333,10.2083},{-1.11111,1.11111}},{{-20.322,2200.},{-2.,2.}}}`.

Comment: Sorry about that, thought I checked with a `Quit` before saying something, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works just find to get the `PlotRange`, but now you want to know what the `PlotRangePadding` is.

```
AbsoluteOptions[Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]], PlotRange]
AbsoluteOptions[Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]], PlotRangePadding]
(* {PlotRange -> {{0., 10.}, {-0.999999, 1.}}} *)
(* {PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], 
    Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}} *)
```

This gives the answer in terms of a scaled value, so we can write a function to get the full padded range (edited to test whether the padding is in fact scaled),

```
padRange[range_, padding_] := Module[{scales},
  If[SameQ[Head[padding[[1]]], Scaled],
   scales = padding[[All, 1]];
   range + {-1, 1} scales First@Differences[range]
   , range + padding]
  ]

fullRange[plot_] := 
 Module[{prange, plotrangepadding, paddingscales, unscaledpadding},
  prange = plot // PlotRange;
  plotrangepadding = AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRangePadding][[1, 2]];
  padRange @@@ Transpose@{prange, plotrangepadding}
  ]

fullRange /@ {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-20.322, 2200}, {-2, 2}}]
  }
(* {{{-0.2, 10.2}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
   {{-0.2, 10.2}, {-2., 2.}}, 
   {{-0.2, 10.2}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
   {{-20.322, 2200.}, {-2., 2.}}} *)
```

This shows that if you explicitly set the `PlotRange`, then no padding takes place

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Select[(Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Options), #[[1]] == PlotRange &]

(*  {PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.999999, 1.}}}  *)
```

Have fun!