# How can I get the values of PlotRange used by a ParametricPlot expression?

Tags: plotting

I have a plot that I plotted using `ParametricPlot` with no `PlotRange` option. I want to know the range of $x$ and $y$ values `ParametricPlot` selects. For example, for the following figure I would like to have something like `{{-0.030, -0.0078}, {0.060, 0.0815\}}`. Is there any way to get it?

[image: Graph]

Comment: try `PlotRange[ParametricPlot[....]]`?

Comment: see here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78324/get-axes-range-of-plot

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/4999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AbsoluteOptions should do the job.  Check the documentation for details.  All the best, Ian