# Epilog and Prolog not ploting for small PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have an automated process that produces plots that will be on a y-axis range of somewhere between zero and 1.  I need to highlight certain bands in the plot that are a result of calculations in the process.

Using `Epilog` or `Prolog` seems a sensible approach but these options are not plotting when the y-axis range is "sufficiently" small.

For example, say the process calculates the following `bands`

```
bands = Partition[10 ^6 {100, 250, 500, 1300, 2500}, 2, 1]
```

for a derived function

```
Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I need to highlight the bands with, for example,

```
Graphics@MapIndexed[
   {Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
    Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {Total@#1, 1}]
   } &, bands]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

But this produces an empty `Graphics`.

After some trial and error I discovered that the bands will show if I explicitly set the `AspectRatio`.

```
Graphics[
    MapIndexed[
     {Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
      Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {First@#1, 1}]
     } &, bands], 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, applying the same option to the plot does not produce the highlighted bands.

```
Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[
    {Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
     Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {First@#1, 1}]
    } &, bands]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and even applying `AspectRatio` liberally in `Show` does not result in the desired plot.

```
Show[
 Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
 ,
 Graphics[
  MapIndexed[
    {Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
     Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {First@#1, 1}]
    } &, bands],
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas how to get around this. Please note that I do not know what the function or the bands will be until near the end of the process. I am looking for a general solution of which the above is a basic example.

Also, can anyone else replicate this issue as I believe it to be a bug.  Mma 11.3 on Win 10.

Comment: Try restarting your kernel -- I see the plot with the stripes.

Comment: @bills Yeah, I tried that before posting.  Even restarted Mma.  No joy.  What version and OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
plt0 = Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6}];
yrange = PlotRange[plt0][[2]];
epilog = MapIndexed[{Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
   Rectangle[{Last@#1, First@yrange}, {First@#1, Last@yrange}]} &, bands];

Show[plt0, Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: Que! Since when has `PlotRange` been a function that would return the `PlotRange` `AbsoluteOptions` of a graphic?  This is news to me; and apparently to the documentation as well.

Comment: @Edmund, it is undocumented. It has been 
 used in a number of posts on this site: [see this and the links there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78329/125)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with v11.3 on my Mac

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Note that `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` is the default for [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Options[Plot, AspectRatio]

(* {AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio} *)

Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6}, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[{Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
     Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {First@#1, 1}]} &, bands]]
```

[image]

I recommend that you use [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) and [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) to make the `Plot` stand out better from the bands.

```
Plot[x 10^-17, {x, 50 10^6, 500 10^6},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Prolog -> MapIndexed[{Opacity[.25, ColorData[110][First@#2]], 
     Rectangle[{Last@#1, 0}, {First@#1, 1}]} &, bands]]
```

[image]